# Question about Classifying singular points and finding corresponding residues from Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis

I wanted to check if I had the right idea : 
Singularities have 3 classification 'essential'.'removabe' and 'pole order x'

a singularity is essential if when you expand it,it is a never ending series and contains no z^ negative powers

a singularity is removable if when you expand it,it is a never ending series and contains no z^postive powers

if a function contains both postive and negative powers for z^ then it is of pole order x, with  x being the highest negative power of z

Is this correct ?

Comment: *Functions* aren't removable, essential, etc. *Singularities* are.

Comment: ah yes thanks, but do I have the right general idea ?

Comment: it seems a bit confused. An essential singularity has infinitely many $z^{-k}$ terms in the functions Laurent expansion about the point; a removable singularity means that the function's Laurent expansion about the singularity is just a Taylor expansion (no $z^{-k}$ terms)

Comment: a yes I got them mixed up I think. How would I know a singularity is of pole order ? is it if the Laurent Expansion has only a fine amount of $$z^(-k)$$ terms ?

Comment: Yes, a singularity is a pole if it has finitely many $z^{-k}$ terms, and its order is the greatest such $k$.